# Generate a pcap file at the end of a Python script

Tags: python, pcap, scapy, sniffing

I wrote a Python script, using Scapy tool, to generate and send packets from a client to server after establishing a TCP connection. I want to generate a pcap file, at the end of my script. The pcap file should contain all traffic generated by the current script. I tried with `sniff()` but the problem is that `sniff()`, when executed, pauses the script and it couldn't run at the same time with other instructions. How can I do this in Scapy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write a list of packets to a PCAP use the [wrpcap](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#pcap) function.

```
>>> wrpcap("temp.cap", pkts)
```

`pkts` is a list of packets. For your implementation you will need to maintain a list of all packets that have been sent and received as your program runs. You can't run a capture and send packets in Scapy.